# How to correctly use a local script variable

Tags: variables

Suppose I have the following code:

```
let s:user_config=fnamemodify('user.vim', ':p')
echom 'file found: ' . s:user_config
if filereadable(s:user_config)  
  source s:user_config
else
  echom s:user_config . 'was not found'
endif
```

If I run this, I get:

```
file found: /home/ninrod/vim_test/user.vim
Error detected while processing /home/ninrod/vim_test/test.vim:
line    4:
E484: Can't open file s:user_config
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

on the echo line, the variable `s:user_config` was correctly interpolated. How do I tell vim to interpolate the `s:user_config` on the source line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is written, your code will execute literally `source s:user_config` and you want to execute `source [content of the variable]`.

You can use `execute()` like this:

```
execute "source " . s:user_config
```

[`:h :execute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3aexecute):

```
:exe[cute] {expr1} ..   Executes the string that results from the evaluation
            of {expr1} as an Ex command.
            Multiple arguments are concatenated, with a space in
            between.  To avoid the extra space use the "."
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you're aware of it, but most of the time we don't need to do what you're trying to achieve the way you're doing it.

If you respect vim standard way of organizing scripts, if you drop your file into `~/.vim/plugin/` it'll be automatically loaded. You cannot know when (regarding the load order of all the scripts in the same directory -- it seems to be sorted lexicographically nowadays), but it'll be loaded. This also means: drop your configuration files in `~/.vim` not in `~/vim_test`.

If you need a mapping/command/abbreviation defined in that plugin, you can enforce its load with `:runtime plugin/user.vim`. Don't forget to add inclusion guards to avoid the script to be loaded twice.

If you need a function from the plugin, then make it an autoload plugin, drop it in: `~/.vim/autoload`. Prefix the function name with the plugin name, like `user#my_function()`, and simply call that function from where you need it: `call user#my_function(parameters)`.

I haven't described the situation with filetype specific configuration, but it isn't much different.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm doing all stuff with docker containers so users can't simply drop their customizatiosn into the aforementioned dir.

Comment: Sometimes I cannot use `$HOME` as I'd like. In those case, I create a `$HOME/luc` directory and I have a `$LUCHOME` variable pointing to it. My [vimrc detects that case and fixes the `'runtimepath'` option](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/vimrc_core.vim#L10) to start everything from `~/luc/.vim`. In the end, I have plugin directory and everything.

Comment: that's clever, thanks for sharing. my specific situation is that I have to honor `user.vim` if that exists in a very custom directory structure: `~/.user/user.vim`, if that exists. `~/.vim` is taken and version controled. So I'm thinking that the solution in the question is simpler.